SwiftUI TabView content passing behind title
I have a SwiftUi List where each item leads to a TabView. When accessing the TabView and scrolling down, the content of the Tab pass behind the current view toolbar.
See example
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
  @Query private var items: [Item]
  
  private var itemsBis: [String] {
    Array(repeating: "Item ", count: 100)
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
      List {
        ForEach(items) { item in
          NavigationLink {
            TabView {
              Tab("Tab 1", systemImage: "house") {
                Form {
                  ForEach(Array(itemsBis.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, item in
                    Text("\(item) \(index + 1)")
                  }
                }
              }
              Tab("Tab 2", systemImage: "circle") {
                Form {
                  ForEach(Array(itemsBis.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, item in
                    Text("\(item) \(index + 1)")
                  }
                }
                
              }
              Tab("Tab 3", systemImage: "gear") {
                Form {
                  ForEach(Array(itemsBis.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, item in
                    Text("\(item) \(index + 1)")
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          } label: {
            Text(item.timestamp, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
          }
        }
      }
    } detail: {
      Text("Select an item")
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
    .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
}


Eventually after a few scrolls or switching tab, the content will display correctly.
What changes should I bring to avoid this behavior?

Note, TabView should be the top most container, not inside a NavigationStack/NavigationSplitView. Each Tab in the TabView would then have their own NavigationStack.

If you apply .padding(.top, 1) to the TabView then this breaks the contact with the safe area inset and stops the Form in the TabView from scrolling through the safe area. But as mentioned in the first comment, this kind of arrangement is unconventional and you may find yourself fighting other undesirable side-effects.
